# How to install Apache httpd as a non root user?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

On our server we have app account with no root privileges. We cannot run Yum or rpm.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download source
2. Decompress it.
3. cd to httpd source directory
4. ./configure --prefix=/home/youruser/httpd -otheroptionshere
5. make install

More detail info about this procedure in the official httpd docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/install.html

Comment: Is there a way to install httpd and only afterwards configure it as non root user ?

Comment: Yes, in User, Groupd directives you can specify a user and also start Apache httpd with that user, just consider that you won't be able to use priviledged TCP ports such as those  < 1024